# Android convert string to ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, android, string, objectinputstream

I'm trying to construct an ObjectInputStream from a string but I'm getting a java.io.StreamCorruptedException:

My code:

```
public static final String PUBLIC_KEY = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA7bO/38XhXYLJikoEEQ7s\naHKYcrrkD2Q+IWS6P0GOOvoX0rfRI6Hb30ETBE/ySzV6F9tpgtCbjU/w7tE8vmOy\nxQDwToUobbS+uZDi+F72PAY9NRKRogtY7YCwJuvAxNVmsTu9i/P/oA3qO3l0ge61\nZu3lMf4ujh969T9Dj0fjIdXQGewqk+ROB6UqoIEHTYi9wRdPlxDGnKTrORu5I5hH\n1xQfM0l49ME36G4u3Ipg5Y9Tqr1F8EL82GYeRoSX+xG+brQAdbjnQGrmrW/VFRkT\n9uL327vrRjiOit9yoTNtP3HYk1g5+Db7XdSNi+8KHZOQ3T2xcYFseXNnd7nIGj97\nBwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
public static final String PRIVATE_KEY_FILE = "C:/keys/private.key";


public static void test() {


 Log.d("DEBUG","Original Text: ");
try {

  final String originalText = "top secret text";
  ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;

  InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(PUBLIC_KEY.getBytes());


  //Log.d("DEBUG","Original Text:3 " + convertStreamToString(is));
  // Encrypt the string using the public key
  inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(is);
  final PublicKey publicKey = (PublicKey) inputStream.readObject();
  final byte[] cipherText = encrypt(originalText, publicKey);

  // Decrypt the cipher text using the private key.
  inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(PRIVATE_KEY.getBytes()));
  final PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) inputStream.readObject();
  final String plainText = decrypt(cipherText, privateKey);

  // Printing the Original, Encrypted and Decrypted Text
  Log.d("DEBUG","Original Text: " + originalText);
  Log.d("DEBUG","Encrypted Text: " +cipherText.toString());
  Log.d("DEBUG","Decrypted Text: " + plainText);

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
  }
```

Could someone explain me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: where is the exception?

Comment: i am not certain you are allowed to do `(PublicKey) inputStream.readObject();` that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write out serializable **object(s)**, strings are serializable, first using the `ObjectOutputStream` to your storage and read the **object(s)** in using the `ObjectInputStream`.

You don't have any object in your byte array storage. That's the reason you are getting the stream corrupted exception.

Following is a very basic snippet to demo -

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
String myStrObj = "Hello World";
oos.writeObject(myStrObj); //write the string as object
oos.close();


ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
String readStrObj = (String) ois.readObject(); //read the string as object
ois.close();
System.out.println(readStrObj);
```

You can replace that `Hello World` with your public key and see what it prints out.